# Como lleno un ObservableList a partir de un ArrayList?

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a juguetear con JavaFX,  intento hacer que una TableView muestre los elementos de una Base de Datos. 
Para eso, cree una clase (Metodos) con un metodo que llena un arrayList (Me funciona joya con Jtable de Swing).

El metodo devuelve una ArrayList llamada list.

Como puedo hacer para que un ObservableList que tengo en el controlador de la ventana, se llene con esta "list" que se obtiene con ese metodo??

Comment: tienes algun codigo que hallas creado ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que estás trabajando con una TableView:

```
ObservableList list = table.getItems();
```

Con la observableList ahora puedes hacer cualquiera de estas opciones:

```
list.addAll(myArrayList);
```

ó

```
list.setAll(myArrayList);
```